# Number of answers : $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus

> let $f(x)= 1+\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k} \ \ k \in \mathbb{R}$
> Number of answers :
>
> $$f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \ \   \ \ :f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

MY Try :

$$y=1+\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k} \\( y-1)^2=x+k+1-x-k-2\sqrt{(x+k+1)(x+k)}\\(y-1)^2+k-1=-2\sqrt{(x+k+1)(x+k)}\\ ((y-1)^2+k-1)^2=4(x^2+x(2k+1)+k^2+k)$$

now what do i do ?

Comment: It has one solution for $k\leq-2$, else none.

Comment: We should not accept so lousy questions.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Indeed. But why not use your voting privileges, then?

Comment: Please clarify the Question.  Is the function $f^{-1}$ a reciprocal of $f$?  Or a functional inverse, i.e. $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$?  The latter interpretation would make this problem something of a search for *fixed points* of $f(f(x))$.

Comment: @hardmath .functional inverse $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
y=1+\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k},\tag{1}\\
x=1+\sqrt{y+k+1}-\sqrt{y+k}.\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Subtracting (1) from (2) gives
\begin{eqnarray}
x-y&=&(\sqrt{y+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k+1})-(\sqrt{y+k}-\sqrt{x+k})\\
&=&\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{y+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k+1}}-\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{y+k}+\sqrt{x+k}}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ (x-y)\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k}+\sqrt{x+k}}\right]=0.$$
Thus one has either
$$ x=y $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k}+\sqrt{x+k}}\tag{3}. $$
Since (3) does holds, one must have $x=y$ and hence
$$ x=1+\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k}. $$
It is easy to see that $x$ is the real roots of the following equation
$$x(x^3-8x^2+12x-4)-4k(x+1)^2=0.\tag{4}$$
The number of answers depends on the real solutions of (4), either 1,2,3 or 4, depending on $k$.

Comment: let $k=3$ then  $x(x^3-8x^2+12x-4)-4(3)(x+1)^2=0$ has two real solution. but $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ has one solution .see this https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: and this $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k}+\sqrt{x+k}}\tag{3}. $ Why did not you solve?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{y+k+1}>\sqrt{y+k}$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k+1}+\sqrt{x+k+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+k}+\sqrt{x+k}}$ has no solution.

Comment: For the first question, the solutions of $y=1+\sqrt{x+k+1}-\sqrt{x+k}$ are solutions of $x(x^3-8x^2+12x-4)-4k(x+1)^2=0$.  However some solutions of the former equation are not solutions of the latter.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628179/number-of-answers-fx-f-1x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Point of intersection of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ while same as that  of $f(x)$ and the line $y=x$.

Comment: let $k=1.53$ ...

Comment: @Fricul38 Check [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mjfnuekz8w)

Comment: if $k=1.53$ then It has three solution .

Comment: @Fricul38 there isn't see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r6xkytolqn)